# navigation between viewcontrollers when orientation changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation-changes

I am developing ios  application that uses two viewcontrollers A and B. A supports both orientations landscape and portrait, when B is only in portrait mode. my goal is B viewcontroller always to be only in portrait mode when I navigate from A to B .I make restrictions on B viewcontroller in the navigationcontroller.

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate

{
    _navigation = (MBNavigationController *) self.frontViewController;

    id currentViewController = [_navigation visibleViewController];

    if ([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[MBViewController class]])
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

when A is in portrait orientation and I navigate to B everything works fine. but when A is in landscape mode and I do the same, part of the B controller view is out scenes. please help me to find the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is present the B viewController with another navigationController in which

```
// sysversion>=ios6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
// sysversion<=ios5
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: can you explain in details? what storyboard tree should I have in such a case?

Comment: two navigation controllers. navigation controller one's root view controller is your A view controller. two's root view controller is B view controller. set `shouldAutorotate` separately